# How to define (sparse) variable diagonal tensors

Tags: tensorflow

In a problem I want to solve using Tensorflow, I want to build a `n-dimensional` rank tensor that is 'diagonal' by blocks. That is, I want to generate a tensor object from a concatenation of low order tensors.

I have tried to define the whole `tf.Variable` tensor and then to impose the value `0` to some variables but Tensorflow does not allow assignments when working with variable tensors.

Moreover, I would want to create 'diagonal' tensors with the same independent variables, as, for example, using a stacked 2D representation, being A a 2 dimensional tensor:

```
T = [A, 0;0 , A]
```

**My current source code:**

```
shape1 = [3,3,10,10]
shape2 = [3,3]
i1 = tf.truncated_normal(shape1, stddev=1.0, dtype = tf.float32)
i2 = tf.truncated_normal(shape2, stddev=1.0, dtype = tf.float32)
A = tf.Variable(i1)
V = tf.Variable(i2)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if i != j:
            A[:,:,i,j] = tf.zeros((3,3))
        else:
            A[:,:,i,j] = V
```

Of course, this code returns the error `Variable object does not support item assignment`.

What I want, at the end of the day, is to define a variable tensor such as:

```
T[:,:,i,j] = tf.zeros([D0,D1]), if i != j
```

and

```
T[:,:,i,j] = A, if i = j

with A = tf.variable([D0,D1])
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use tf.stack, which converts a list of tensors of dimension n to a tensor of dimension n+1.

```
l = []
for i in range(10):
    li = [V * 0.0 if i != j else V for j in range(10)]
    Ai = tf.stack(li)
    l.append(Ai)

A = tf.stack(l)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to ask for a slightly different situation, that is when the stacking direction is not the associated to the last index.

For example, if I have a tensor of rank [10,10,3,3,10,10] and I want to stack the 'diagonal blocks' in the 3-4 slots.

Comment: You could build a tensor of rank [10, 10, 10, 10, 3, 3] stacking the blocks in the 5-6 slots, then use tf.transpose(A, perm=[0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3])  to move the blocks to the 3-4 slots